# ¿Cómo se ha elegido el color del favicon para los sitios en otros idiomas?

Tags: discusión

Me he fijado que cada uno de los sitios de StackOverflow en otro idioma tiene el favicon en un color distinto:

[image]

¿Se ha seguido algún criterio para elegir estos colores, o ha sido al azar?

Comment: en pocas palabas, ta - te - ti suerte para .. ti ;)

Comment: Parece algo arbitrario, no conozco ninguna asociación idioma-color que pueda servir de base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cómo [bien dicho por @Konamiman](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25/c%C3%B3mo-se-ha-elegido-el-color-del-favicon-para-los-sitios-en-otros-idiomas/36#36), está claro que el color de la banderas ha marcado el diseño de las logos.

El caso Brasil/Portugal es perfecto porque las dos tienen verde en sus banderas. Pero, que quede claro, el mercado principal y objetivo de Stack Exchange era Brasil desde el principio. Y como ese país se auto-define como "verde y amarillo", pues **verde**.

El caso Español y sus antiguas colonias es un poco más complicado... aquí, creo yo, el mercado está diluido, no hay un país dominante (por población o potencial económico <sub><sup>-ya discutiremos la geopolitica a parte</sup></sub>). Lo único es que España detiene el "copyright" del idioma, igual que Portugal: en Brasil se estudia Gramática Portuguesa, no Gramática Brasileña.

Pero me pierdo... veamos las banderas de América Latina <sup><sub>(sabiendo que España es roja y amarilla)</sub></sup>:

[image: banderas latino america]

[Japón](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) solo puede ser **rojo** (¿sería posible el blanco?).
Entonces a [Rusia](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) solo le queda el **azul**.

### ¿Y nosotros? Pues, *¡el amarillo!*

Comment: Me quedo con el amarillo porque así completamos la trinidad de los colores primarios :P

Answer (score 2):

Ahora que me fijo, podrían ser colores representativos de las banderas de España, Portugal (¿Brasil?), Japón y Rusia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muy buena.............

Answer (score 1):

No sé en base a qué se habrá elegido. Pero sé que **las banderas representan países, no idiomas**. A mí personalmente me molesta ver que en una carta de un restaurante se represente el inglés con la bandera inglesa o el español con la bandera española. Y no tiene que ver con romanticismo patrio ya que soy alemán.

Así que elegir un color representativo por país no lo veo, y los idiomas no tienen colores.

Si se quiere *tirar* por banderas, lo más justo sería coger la media de color de todas las banderas donde se hable español. De la imagen que puso @brasofilo saldría un `#927686`:

[image]

Estética matemática. Horrible, sí.