# ¿Quienes son los encargados del diseño y las características nuevas de SOes?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Hace poco me fijé en una característica de SOes que no había visto en otros sitios y es la notificación de preguntas nuevas.

[image: notificador de imagenes]

Quizás es algo que sea común en otros sitios pero no lo había visto antes. Indagué un poco en el meta de StackExchange y aprendí un poco de como es el [proceso de graduación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263679/timeline-of-a-stack-exchange-site) y en que fase se escoge el diseño para el sitio nuevo.

[Feedback Requested: Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation)

[Design-Independent Graduation is on for early September!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september)

También como fue escogido el color del ícono del sitio en una pregunta del meta

[¿Cómo se ha elegido el color del favicon para los sitios en otros idiomas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25/c%C3%B3mo-se-ha-elegido-el-color-del-favicon-para-los-sitios-en-otros-idiomas)

No pude encontrar en ningún lugar excepto [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58397/where-should-we-post-feature-requests-for-stack-exchange-betas) algo que me orientara acerca de como las nuevas características(no hablo de estilos) son aprobadas/creadas para los diferentes sitios y se trata de una pregunta muy antigua que puede no tener validez ya así que pregunto:

¿Quien hizo el notificador de preguntas nuevas para este sitio?

¿Que mecanismo tiene que seguir para decidir y agregar características particulares al sitio? (¿Hay alguno? ¿Quizas sugerencias de los moderadores?)

Nota:

Se que hay un [tag](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) del meta para esto pero no pude encontrar ninguna pregunta asociada y aunque la hubiera no me podría responder quien es el que hace los cambios y cómo.

Pensé también en postearla en el meta de StackExchange pero la pregunta sólo aplica a este sitio así que me pareció que es este el lugar apropiado para hacerla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según entiendo en términos generales los encargados del diseño gráfico y de la programación del sitio son los mismos que el del resto de los sitios de la red de Stack Exchange. Me parece que un buen lugar para aprender es el blog de la compañía el cual recientemente fue renombrado de nuevo como Stack Overflow -> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/.

Más en específico, recuerdo haber visto alguna pregunta aquí sobre el diseño/funcionalidad del sitio en la que un miembro del equipo de diseño/programación publicó un comentario o respuesta. Es cosa de "buscarle" :)